# flask app not working on kubernetes for larger file

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes

I am very new to developing a flask app and deploying on kubernetes. My app is currently providing 2 functionalities

It has 2 forms - one is textform and second one is file upload
for textform - it will accept an adhoc file from user > saves in input_files folder >  do some changes(using another python file) > save in output_folder >  post it back to user as changedfile

for upload - user can upload multiple files > gets saved in input folder >  do some changes(using another python file) > save in output_files > zip the changed files and download in user local machine

[enter image description here][1]

This code is working on localhost, recently deployed on kubernetes and only textform works fine for < 900b(very small size) but it is throwing error 400 for larger file size. I am not sure if the response is getting stuck due to size or some other issue but I am stuck.

Sample code

```
@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
            adhoc_file_name = 'adhoc_file.sql'
            if request.method == 'POST':
                text = request.form['my']
                with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], adhoc_file_name), 'w') as f:
                    f.write(str(text))
                x = migration()                    
                x.transform_files()
            f.close()
            return redirect('/changedfile/')
        elif request.form['action'] == 'upload':
            if 'files[]' not in request.files:
                flash('No file part')
                return redirect(request.url)
            files = request.files.getlist('files[]')
            for file in files:
                if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
                    x = transform_file()
            return redirect('/downloadfile/')

@app.route('/changedfile/')
def display_file():
    print("in display file method")
    target = DOWNLOAD_FOLDER
    with open(os.path.join(target, 'adhoc_file.sql'), 'r') as rd:
        return render_template('content.html', text=rd.read())
    rd.close()
```

My form for textarea

```
<html>
    <form method="POST" id="form1" >
        <input type="hidden">
            <textarea name="mysql_text">Enter Your SQL</textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="adhoc_sql" value="submit">
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you talk more about how your kubernetes is setup? Is it behind a reverse proxy? Is it using an ingress controller?

Comment: yes it is, I am getting this error werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. For some reason my form works fine for small request but giving me error for little larger file 
KeyError: 'mysql_text'

Comment: This same request works fine inside my pod (interactive shell mode)